# Latest installed node version not loading on startup

Tags: node.js, shell, terminal, zsh

I've installed the latest node version as you can see in the image on the left-hand terminal. I updated to the latest LTS ages ago, but whenever I start up a new window (right-hand terminal) I'm apparently still using an older version of node. In this screenshot too, I switched to the latest LTS and then opened the right-hand terminal, but it's still saying I'm using `12.20.1`.

How can I ensure I have the latest LTS version of node each time I open my terminal?

If it's relevant: I'm using iTerm2, but I get the same response when I use the native Mac terminal or when I use the embedded VSCode terminal.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should actually update the version by passing it to NVM:

```
nvm list // will give list 

nvm use nodeversion

nvm alias default nodeversion
```

Now, restart your terminal and check node version. It will be the last updated one. Whenever you change the version try to change the default version to new one.

Updating node to latest:

```
nvm alias default node

nvm use default
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I had to hardcode in the version because it didn't recognise `nvm alias default lts/*` -- I thought that might mean the default would always be the latest lts, but apparently you can only put in a specific version when setting the default.

Comment: You can do that too, I update it in the answer.